# Trying to display alert in Chrome extension options page, but get "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to display a little status box in my options page on my chrome extension. I am trying to follow the example in the documentation [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/options.html).

But I am getting an exception `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined`. The example never defines a status object but I am such a noob at javascript/html that I don't know if there is something obvious I am missing.  Here is the code for my options page.

There error is happening on the 2nd line of the callback function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function login(event){
                event.preventDefault();
        var username = document.getElementById("username");
        var password = document.getElementById("password");
        if(username.value != null && password.value != null) chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().login(username, password, callback);
    }
    function callback(){
            status = document.getElementById("status");
        status.innerHTML = "Now logged in";
        setTimeout(function(){
                status.innerHTML = "";
        }, 750);
    }
</script>
<body>
<form>
Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /> <br />
Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /> <br />
<button onclick="login(event)">Login</button>
</form>
<div id="status"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you update your code to include the addition suggested by Digital Plane so we can try work out why it's still not working.

Comment: @Alasdair I updated the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are submitting a `form` the page is being reloaded when you click *Login*. To avoid this, you can call [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault) and pass the event in to the `login` function as follows;

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    function login(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var username = document.getElementById("username");
        var password = document.getElementById("password");
        if(username.value != null && password.value != null) chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().login(username, password, callback);
    }
    function callback(){
        var status = document.getElementById("status");
        status.innerHTML = "Now logged in";
        setTimeout(function(){
                status.innerHTML = "";
        }, 750);
    }
    </script>
    <body>
    <form>
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /> <br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /> <br />
    <button onclick="login(event)">Login</button>
    </form>
    <div id="status"></div>
    </body>
```

This will stop the `form` from submitting and works as you'd expect.

Comment: not getting the error anymore but its not displaying any text anywhere either.

Comment: ok I was missing the 'var' on the status thanks for your help its working!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an HTML element with id `status`, which causes the error because `document.getElementById()` returns `null` or `undefined` when it can't find an element.
To fix it, just add an element with id `status`.
Ex.

```
<button onclick="login()">Login</button>
</form>

<div id="status"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be incorrect, but I don't have any experience with the "chrome.extension". If you change 
`var status = document.getElementById("status");
    status.innerHTML = "Now logged in";`

into `var status = window.document.getElementById("status");
    status.innerHTML = "Now logged in";`

Notice the added 'window', perhaps the callback tries to search the 'chrome.extension.document' instead of 'window.document' ?